# If $a_n \rightarrow 1$, does $X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} X$ implies $a_n X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} X$?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

The title pretty much sums it up.

I'm trying to prove that $S_n^2 \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \sigma^2$. So far, I have:

$S_n^2 = \frac{n}{n-1} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \frac{n}{n-1} \bar{X}_n^2$

And I proved that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{E}(X^2)$ and $\bar{X}_n^2 \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{E}(X)^2$.

Given that $\frac{n}{n-1} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, all I have left to do (I think) is to prove the thing in the title (I'm presuming it's true).

I'm an computer engineering student and English is not my mother tongue, so I apologize for the grammar errors and (more likely) the lack of math rigor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In econometrics the result is known as [Slutsky's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem). The extension that Davide mentioned is then obtained using the [Continuous Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem).

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that theorem, but I didn't know that I could use it with a non-random sequence. Is that the case?

Comment: A deterministic sequence is a special case of a random sequence. Each element in the sequence is a random variable with a degenerate (dirac) law.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{|a_n-1|\cdot |X_n|< 2\delta\}\cap \{|X_n-X|< \delta\}\subset\{|a_nX_n-X|< 3\delta\}$, we have 
$$P(|a_nX_n-X|\geqslant 3\delta)\leqslant P(|a_n-1|\cdot |X_n|\geqslant 2\delta)+P(|X_n-X|\geqslant \delta),$$
and by a similar argument,
$$P(|a_nX_n-X|\geqslant 3\delta)\leqslant P(|a_n-1||X_n-X|\geqslant \delta)+P(|a_n-1||X|\geqslant \delta)+P(|X_n-X|\geqslant \delta).$$
For the first term, note that $(|a_n-1|,n\geqslant 1)$ is a bounded sequence. By convergence in probability of $X_n$ to $X$, the first and third term will converge to $0$. For the second one, note that $|a_n-1||X|\to 0$ almost surely.

More generally, one can show that if $X_n\to X$ and $Y_n\to Y$ both in probability, then $f(X_n,Y_n)\to f(X,Y)$ in probability for any continuous $f\colon \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: I'll need to read your answer more carefully, but I think the last thing you said works for me. I'm just not sure with respect to the doubt that I mentioned to Alex. But thanks anyway.